# How do I configure kafka-connect-spooldir to consume a json array?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I've configured kafka-connect-spooldir to consume files containing JSON objects according to the instructions at https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir.  This consumes files containing one or more JSON objects.  Now how can I configure this to consume a file containing a JSON array instead?

Here is my current key and value schemas:

```
key.schema={"name": "com.example.users.UserKey", "type": "STRUCT", "isOptional": false, "fieldSchemas": {"id": {"type": "INT64", "isOptional": false }}}
value.schema={"name": "com.example.users.User", "type": "STRUCT", "isOptional": false, "fieldSchemas": {"id": {"type": "INT64", "isOptional": false}, "test": {"type": "STRING", "isOptional": true}}}
```

Here is a sample of my data:

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "test": "Carla Howe"
}
{
  "id": 1,
  "test": "Gayle Becker"
}
```

Here is what I would like the data to look like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 10,
    "test": "Carla Howe"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "test": "Gayle Becker"
  }
]
```

I've tried simply to change the first type from STRUCT to ARRAY, but this throws an NPE "valueSchema cannot be null".

Can someone please point me in the right direction, or provide an example?

Comment: This is still an issue.  Anyone out there doing this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://jcustenborder.github.io/kafka-connect-documentation/projects/kafka-connect-spooldir/sources/SpoolDirJsonSourceConnector.html) there is a SchemaGenerator tool that can be run to generate the schema for sample data.